# How can I avoid a table (datatable) being truncated in a flexdashboard container by an additional text?

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, dt, flexdashboard

When there is a text above a datatable object, the table is truncated and the pagination is no longer visible.

Is it possible to size the datatable to that it fits in one flexdashboard container?

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r, results='asis'}
cat("This is a text\n\nThis is a text")
```

```{r}
mtcars %>% datatable(options = list(dom = 'tp'))
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options. You could use `vertical_layout: scroll`. This will allow the pagination to work while keeping the text in the same container as the table.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: scroll
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r, results='asis'}
cat("This is a text\n\nThis is a text")
```

```{r}
mtcars %>% datatable(options = list(dom = 'tp'))
```
````

Alternatively you could use separate containers for the text and the table. You would probably want to set the height of the containers with `{data-height}` if you do this.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(DT)
```

Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Text A {data-height=50}

```{r, results='asis'}
cat("This is a text\n\nThis is a text")
```

### Chart A

```{r}
mtcars %>% datatable(options = list(dom = 'tp'))
```
````